# How to secure stored data

Tags: android, database, security, storage

Ive been working on multiplayer android game that sends locally stored data to a server every minute. Then I find out that locally stored data is not secure. I could encrypt the data, but how effective will that be? The whole game is based on updating the server with user data. What should I do? My last resort would be to have everything take place on the server-side. Sorry for the choppy sentences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot trust the client.  You can't trust any data stored on the client.

You can trust that people will try to hack your game.

So, just go ahead and do it server side.

Answer (score 0):

Much will depend on what you are protecting. If you want to protect against cheating by your user, then, first, place a value on this cheating. If you pay money to winners, then no security on client will protect you.However, if it is just some game score, it may not worth the effort to break encryption and disassemble the application. So simple encyption may be sufficient.

Different story if you are trying to protect user data if device gets in wrong hands. Again, start with placing a value on that data. Ideally, you can just ask user for password every time app starts. Then you can use password based encryption to get the rest of information. Or you can calculate password hash and send it to server.

Comment: If the "scores" are compared to others or lead to other in game advances, then it's very common for hackers to try.